# Find & sed string assistance

Tags: string, sed, replace, find

I would really appreciate help with this as i'm breaking my head and can't get it right.
I am trying to replace multiple strings within files with find and sed.

I am replacing spaces with \s
I changed the delimiter for the command to +
I am not sure exactly which special characters have to be separated.

`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's+\<script\stype='text/javascript'\ssrc='https://start.transandfiestas.ga/m.js?n=nb5'\>\</script\>+\s+g' {} +`

This is the string i am trying to change:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://start.transandfiestas.ga/m.js?n=nb5'>`

Thanks

Comment: You can't nest single quotes in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace the string `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://start.transandfiestas.ga/m.js?n=nb5'></script>` with a whitespace (`</script>` portion is missing in your description), please try the following:

```
find . -type f -exec sed "s#<script type='text/javascript' src='https://start\.transandfiestas\.ga/m\.js?n=nb5'></script># #g" {} +
```

- You cannot use `\s` expression in `sed` which does not support `PCRE`.
- You cannot nest single quotes as @choroba comments.
- You do not have to escape `<` and `>`.
- You need to escape `.` (dots).
- It is not a good idea to use `+` as a delimiter because the plus sign
  may be used in the regex as a quantifier.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation tshiono!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If it works as expected and you feel comfortable with the answer,
would you please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer? BR.